# How to get StructureMap to return a specific instance for a requested type

Tags: c#, structuremap

I want to register a specific instance of an object for a type in structuremap, how can I do that?

For example,

When I do:

```
var myObj = ObjectFactory.GetInstance(typeof(MyAbstractClass));
```

i would like it to return a previously constructed concrete class, which i created like this:

```
var myClass = new MyConcreteClass("bla"); // MyConcreteClass : MyAbstractClass
```

so

```
myObj == myClass
```

How do i register myClass with structuremap to facilitate this?

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you would do this in you initialization

```
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.ForRequestedType<MyAbstractClass>().TheDefault.IsThis(myClass);
        });
```

Where myClass is the instance of the object you want to return.

Comment: Im getting: Type instance MyConcreteClass cannot be plugged into type MyAbstractClass. Any idea?

Comment: Have you gotten this to work? I just looked back and noticed your reply.  I haven't had any issues doing it this way in our application.  Do you get a compile error or a initialization error? You might post the code that is trying to get the instance.

Answer (score 4):

You can inject a concrete instance as the default by

```
ObjectFactory.Inject(typeof(MyAbstractClass), myClass);
```

Comment: This worked well for me. I have a couple of instances of an ISessionFactory that I set up. Each has a name because each points to a different database. After the initial ObjectFactory.Initialize() I then add your code to tell StructureMap that my IWorkorderRepository should point to the correct database:
ObjectFactory.Inject(typeof (IWorkorderRepository), new WorkorderRepository(ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<ISessionFactory>(Resources.CityworksDatasource)));

Answer (score 1):

In StructureMap 3 methods have changed and this code now works:

```
var emailService = new EmailService(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[mykey]);

ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{                
    x.For<IEmailService>().Use(emailService);
});
```